# Change color in PopMenu (Setting)

Tags: android, menu, colors

I need to change color of PopMenu (Setting). I updated style.xml but didn't work. Then a try to change color of Item, didn't work too.
I need a little grey background and white TextColor.

**MyActivity.java extends ActionBarActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.file);
   mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
   mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);
   item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
           openShare();
           return false;
       }
   });
   return true;
}
```

**MyActivity_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_background"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    >
```

**main.xml**(menu)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.MyActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/file"
        android:title="Setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
        app:actionProviderClass=
            "android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider">
    </item>

</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/action_bar_text</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_bar_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/action_bar_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, i just updated :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_background"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
```